# How to format Ben Alman's jQuery Debounce

Tags: jquery, syntax, debouncing

I'm having syntax trouble with [Ben Alman's jQuery Debounce plugin](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/). It works as expected in one format but I need it in another.

**How can I make this work without throwing an error?**

```
coolThing.on({
    keydown: function() {

        console.log('keydown');

        $.debounce(500, function() { // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined :(

            debugLog('debounced keydown');
        })();
    }),
    focus: function() {

        console.log('focus');
    }),
    blur: function() {

        console.log('blur');
    })
});
```

Thanks!!

__

Here are other formats that work:

```
coolThing.keydown($.debounce(500, function() {

    console.log('debounced keydown');
}));

coolThing.on({
    keydown: function() {

        console.log('keydown');
    }),
    focus: function() {

        console.log('focus');
    }),
    blur: function() {

        console.log('blur');
    })
});

coolThing.on({
    keydown: $.debounce(500, function(e) {

        // wouldn't it be great to execute other things before $.debounce()?

        debugLog('debounced keydown');
    }),
    focus: function() {

        console.log('focus');
    }),
    blur: function() {

        console.log('blur');
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work as is. `$.debounce()` returns a "proxy" function, which only runs the event handler if the time elapsed since it was last invoked is greater than the period you specify.

The problem with your code, is that you're creating new `$.debounce()` instances each time the event handler is invoked (therefore new proxy instances), therefore debounce can't track the last invocation time.

Admittedly, the above won't case the TypeError you're experiencing, and, having had a look at the `debounce` source, I'm not sure *where* the TypeError originates from, but once you fix the TypeError, you'll encounter the more fatal issue I outline above.

What you instead want to look to do is:

1. Specify the handlers separately. One for the debounce, another for what you want to happen immediately;

   ```
   coolThing.on({
       keydown: function() {

           console.log('keydown');

       },
       focus: function() {

           console.log('focus');
       },
       blur: function() {

           console.log('blur');
       }
   }).on('keydown', $.debounce(500, function () {

   });
   ```
2. Begin to track this yourself using `setTimeout`.
3. Use a massive IIFE hack;

   ```
   coolThing.on({
       keydown: (function () {
           var bounce = $.debounce(500, function () {

           });

           return function (e) {
               bounce.apply(this, arguments);

               console.log('keydown');
           };
       }()),
       focus: function() {

           console.log('focus');
       },
       blur: function() {

           console.log('blur');
       }
   });
   ```

The alternatives are provided in the order I'd recommend them.

Comment: Bonkers. Better to use Underscore's method then, don't you think? http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

Comment: @technopeasant: I'm pretty sure you'll get the same problems with `_.debounce` as you do with `$.debounce`. Both of them work by returning a context function. If you recreate that context function each time the click handler is invoked, you lose that context.